# How to use PayPal SDK Cordova Plugin in ionic2

Tags: paypal, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Can any one tell how to import and implement Paypal Cordova Plugin in ionic2.

I had install plugin using `cordova plugin add com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk`

[PayPal Cordova Plugin on Github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin)

[Paypal Official Developer Cordova Plugin](https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-cordova-plugin-released/)